# Enable or disable two icons

Tags: php, html, css, comparative-review

I need two icons:

1. If the email is verified, show an icon without a hyperlink and set an "activated" CSS class for green style and checked.
2. If the email is not verified, the icon is linked to the verify page, and the default is a gray color style.

Which of these solutions is better and standard?

## Solution #1:

```
<a href="<?php echo ($modelStatic->isVerifiedEmail) ? 'javascript:void(0)' :
    Yii::app()->createUrl('/user/reActivate'); ?>"
   class="item<?php if($modelStatic->isVerifiedEmail) echo ' activated'; ?>">
    <div class="confirm-icon">
        <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
        <?php echo Yii::t('app', 'Verify Email'); ?>
    </div>
</a>
<style>
.activated {
    cursor: default;
}
</style>
```

## Solution #2:

```
if($modelStatic->isVerifiedEmail) : ?>
    <div class="item activated">
        <div class="confirm-icon">
            <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="text">
            <?php echo Yii::t('app', 'Verify Email'); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php else: ?>
    <a href="<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('/user/reActivate'); ?>"
       class="item">
        <div class="confirm-icon">
            <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="text">
            <?php echo Yii::t('app', 'Verify Email'); ?>
        </div>
    </a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

## Solution #3:

```
<?php if($modelStatic->isVerifiedEmail) : ?>
    <div class="item activated">
<?php else: ?>
    <a href="<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('/user/reActivate'); ?>" class="item">
<?php endif; ?>
        <div class="confirm-icon">
            <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="text">
            <?php echo Yii::t('app', 'Verify Email'); ?>
        </div>
<?php if($modelStatic->isVerifiedEmail) : ?>
    </div>
<?php else: ?>
    </a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about standard, so I'll just say what I see.

I found that the second is cleanest of all three and easiest to read.  The logic flow is very simple, with just one simple if/else.  However, it is not DRY, with all the problems that that entails.

the first and third are both a bit more complex.
the third also has the same `if` block defined twice (once at the beginning and once at the end), which makes it also not DRY

regarding the first, I personally don't like the idea of creating an `a` tag that gets `javascript:void(0)`. It seems that it will just add clutter to the rendered page.

The other problem (with all three) is that you have your logic mixed in to the html. I would recommend something like as follows:

```
<?php 
    //first define all the variable items
if($modelStatic->isVerifiedEmail) : 
    $startTag = '<div class="item activated">';
    $endTag = '</div>';
else:
    $startTag = '<a href="<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('/user/reActivate'); class="item">'
    $endTag = '</a>';
endif; ?>


     <?=$startTag?>
        <div class="confirm-icon">
            <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="text">
            <?php echo Yii::t('app', 'Verify Email'); ?>
        </div>
     <?=$endTag?>
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, the second solution is better from readability point of view. The other solutions are too clutter and obviously have higher [cyclomatic complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity).

I think it would be a cleaner code base if you could use a template engine like twig and it could be more fun with haml I could find a couple of package in packagist [for Yii2](https://packagist.org/packages/mervick/yii2-mthaml) and other frameworks.

using twig/haml2, second solution would be like:

```
{% if $modelStatic->isVerifiedEmail %}
  .item.activated
    .confirm-icon
      %i.fa.fa-envelope-o
    .text
      {{ Yii::t('app', 'Verify Email') }}
{% else %}
  %a{:href => {{ Yii::app()->createUrl('/user/reActivate') }}, :class => 'item'}
    .confirm-icon
      %i.fa.fa-envelope-o
    .text
      {{ Yii::t('app', 'Verify Email') }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. This is a personal opinion, but I feel like your answer is missing a bit of "meat". Could you add some supporting source or expert that would help you point about the version 2 being more readable or solution #1 and #3 being cluttered ? Could you give an example of template too, to give a perspective to the OP of the code what it could look like!

Comment: I don't talk about readability, and I thinks the solution #3 is better for develop. Also, middle of block tag is duplicate in solution #2. Is not it?

Comment: you're right about redundancy. but other solutions are so complicated, they do more harm than good. string duplication would no hide any bug. but nasty `if`s does. ;)